# If $N$ is a normal subgroup of semidirect product group of $N$ and $H$ where $H$ is generated by $a$ and $b$, is $ab=ba$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation, semidirect-product

I need help to get the idea of the presentation of semidirect products groups. I got this question from an example the $A_4$ is a semidirect product of $N=\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle (1 2 3)\rangle$.

> If $N$ is a normal subgroup of semidirect product group of $N$ and $H$ where $N$ is generated by $a$ and $b$, is $ab=ba$? If so why?

I know if $H$ and $N$ are both normal and their intersection is trivial, then $hn=nh$ for all $h$ in $H$ and $n$ in $N$, but not sure why in semidirect case.

regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There are plenty of nonabelian groups with 2 generators which arise as $N$ for some semidirect product. Consider $S_5 = C_2 \ltimes A_5$. Here $N = A_5$ is nonabelian yet generated by two elements.

Comment: After the edit, I think I may have misinterpreted your question, but I'm not sure. You say $N = \langle a, b \rangle$ but then later you say $H$ is generated by $a$ and $b$. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks for asking I mean $N$ is generated by a and b.

Comment: Ok - then I think $S_5 = C_2 \ltimes A_5$ remains a counterexample, since $A_5 = \langle (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4,5) \rangle$

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of adding a proper answer so that future users know how to spend their time:

The symmetric group $S_5 = C_2 \ltimes A_5$ is a counterexample, since
$A_5 = N = \langle(1,2,3), (1,2,3,4,5)\rangle$ yet is nonabelian.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\ge3$.

$S_n=\langle(12),(123\dots n)\rangle$.

And any index two subgroup is normal.

So $S_n\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$ will do as a counterexample.

Comment: sounds perfect  Chris. Thank you so much.